# mongoose search in phone numbers where it is not uniformed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

in my database the filed phone has many formats like '1-641-774-5186' , '+16417745186' ,'16417745186' and '(1641)-774-5186' now how can I search in all this formats at once.

Comment: I would clean up the entire database with something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js

Comment: I dont know if its possible to ignore all the characters, but you can make use of aggregation framework to achieve this conversion and then run the search. But remember that it would slow down your queries a bit. So better decide a format and save all your numbers in that consistent format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can try to use the regex to search on your number key. Here is the link to the official document: [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Example:

Your query could look like something this

```
db.sample.find({no: /641/})
```

and this will give all the match documents with the regex

```
{ "no" : "1-641-774-5186" }
{ "no" : "+16417745186" }
{ "no" : "16417745186" }
{ "no" : "(1641)-774-5186" }
```

This is just an example but you can build a regex of your own so that it will match all the uses cases

To generate a regex you can use some custom function that will modify the search text as per your requirement. Here is an example of such a function which will generate a regex.

```js
function getRegexForLimitedUseCases(searchText){
  let start = "";
  let atIndex1 = "";
  let atIndex4 = "";
  let atIndex5 = "";
  let atIndex7 = "";

  if(searchText.length > 0){
    start = "^([\\+\\(]{0,1})";
  }
  
  if(searchText.length > 1){
    atIndex1 = "([-]{0,1})";
  }
  
  if(searchText.length > 4){
    atIndex4 = "([-\\)]{0,2})";
  }
  
  if(searchText.length > 7){
    atIndex7 = "([-]{0,2})";
  }
  
  return start + searchText[0] + atIndex1 + searchText.substr(1,3) + atIndex4 + searchText.substr(4,3) + atIndex7 + searchText.substr(7); 
}

function getRegexForGenericUseCases(searchText){
  let fillerRegex = "([-\\+\\(\\)]{0,2})";
  return fillerRegex + searchText.split("").join(fillerRegex)
}

console.log(getRegexForLimitedUseCases("16417745186"))
console.log(getRegexForGenericUseCases("16417745186"))
```

Here is an example of a query

```
db.sample.find({no: { $regex: "^([\+\(]{0,1})1([-]{0,1})641([-\)]{0,2})774([-]{0,2})5186" }},{_id: 0})
```

**Output**

```
{ "no" : "1-641-774-5186" }
{ "no" : "+16417745186" }
{ "no" : "16417745186" }
{ "no" : "(1641)-774-5186" }
```

Comment: I tried this but when I write the full number it give back nothing

Comment: You can create your own regex before supplying it into the query, I have updated my answer with some more details